# How to make loading of template after ngOnInit. Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

When I am logged in and go to the login I shortly see the login form and then the normal dashboard. The login form should not be visible at all for logged in users when they visit the main page. If they visit they should be "redirected" to the main page (without showing the login form).

As I understand I need to make loading template after ngOnInit, or make condition before template is loaded.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем вы задаете вопрос на английском языке на русском SO? + вопрос вообще непонятный, что вы хотите сделать? какая загрузка шаблона после `ngOnInit`?

Comment: У меня шаблон загружается и тогда идет редирект. Надо чтоб редирект был и шаблон не грузился если юзер залогинен

Comment: что значит шаблон загружается ?

Comment: страница templateUrl

Comment: шаблоны компилируются еще до того, как стартанет ваше приложение. Так что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: чтоб он не отображался, если я залогинен, перейду на страницу логин мне отобразит форму и через несколько секунд будет редирект то что в ngOnInit

Comment: Надо чтоб сразу без отображания страницы логин формы

Comment: извините, не хочу показаться грубым, но я вообще ничего не понимаю :( давайте по сути, каков алгоритм? пользователь заходит на такой-то роут (например `/`), видит то-то, кликает на кнопку логин и переходит на другой роут (`/login` как пример), что происходит дальше? у вас на одной странице и форма, и другие данные, и вы хотите скрывать форму если пользователь авторизован или как?

Comment: Когда я делаю вход меня кидает на /index, после того если я в урлу напишу /login, при этом юзер авторизован, надо чтоб не отобразилась страница логина та что указана в templateUrl, а кинуло на /index, оно как бы счс так работает, но несколько секунд отображает страницу логин, просто не успевает проверку пройти

Comment: какой предикат того, что юзер залогинен? если юзер авторизован - вы храните данные в локалсторедж? если юзер залогинен, вы хотите чтобы он не смог получить доступ к `/login` и вернулся на `/index`?

Comment: если юзер залогинен, вы хотите чтобы он не смог получить доступ к /login и вернулся на /index? да .   Сейчас оно работает но юзер всеравно видет пару секунд страницу, пока пройдет проверка на существования в локалсторедже

Comment: ок, оформлю ответ, вы проделаете действия и дальше мы будем двигаться с вами дальше

Answer (score 1):

В Angular есть концепция защитников (guards), которые как раз таки решают вашу проблему. Они могут ограничить доступ к определенным роутам по определенным условиям, как и в данном случае, что хотите сделать вы - ограничить доступ к роуту `/login`, если пользователь авторизован. Защитник - это всего лишь обычная функция:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    public canActivate(): boolean {
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

        if (user) {
            return this.router.navigateByUrl('/index') && false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

`CanActivate` - это интерфейс и синтаксический сахар (<s>скажем нет утиной типизации</s>), заставляет класс реализовывать метод `canActivate`.

Так как `AuthGuard` маркирован декоратором `Injectable` - мы делаем вывод, что это провайдер и он должен быть зарегистрирован в метаданных модуля, чтоб инжектор имел доступ к нашему сервису:

```
import { AuthGuard } from './путь-к-auth-guard.ts';

@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    declarations: [...],
    bootstrap: [...],
    providers: [AuthGuard]
})
```

Для избежания до того, чтобы постоянно не импортить сервисы и не регистрировать их в `providers` - апгрейднитесь до 6 версии Angular, там есть поддержка `tree-shakable` провайдеров.

Теперь дело за малым, нужно сказать роутеру какой роут следует проверить на доступ, я не знаю вашей конфигурации роутера, покажу на примере:

```
// app.router.module.ts

import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuard } from './путь-к-auth-guard.ts';

const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'index',
    component: КомпонентIndex
}, {
    path: 'login',
    component: КомпонентLogin,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}];

export const AppRouterModule: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Теперь, когда пользователь попытается перейти по роуту `/login` - модуль роутера вызовет метод `canActivate`, который вернет `boolean`, если вернет `true` - значит можно активировать компонент, если `false` - то перекинет не `index`.